# VisualSVN SHOWS Wrong URL

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have created a repository named MyRepo, and was using url 
 https://servername/svn/MyRepo

but from few days url automatically redirect to https://servername/!/#MyRepo

Answer (score 1):

This behavior of URL modification is usual if you access repositories through web browser.

But you can get a proper URL for Subversion client.

1. On the VisualSVN Server web interface, navigate to the desired path in the
   Subversion repository.
2. Click the Checkout button at the top right-hand side of the web interface.
   [image: Checkout button]
3. Copy the repository URL to clipboard.
4. Paste the repository URL to your Subversion client program.